# Tiny RTC I2C module not working

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, rtc, wire-library

I bought a Tiny RTC I2C module and it doesn't work.
When i run the TimeRTCSet from TIME library all i get is:

```
Unable to sync with the RTC
0:00:00 0 0 1970
0:00:01 1 1 1970
0:00:02 1 1 1970
0:00:03 1 1 1970
0:00:04 1 1 1970
0:00:05 1 1 1970
0:00:06 1 1 1970
0:00:07 1 1 1970
```

The module is connected like this:

Vin -> 5V
Gnd -> Gnd
SCL -> A5
SDA -> A4

I'm using arduino uno.

I tried with a simple i2c scanner, but it returned two devices!

```
Scanning...
I2C device found at address 0x50  !
I2C device found at address 0x68  !
done
```

Only the clock is connected. I tried removing the battery for night to reset it, but it didn't fix it.

Could you help me?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a link to the I2C RTC you are using.

Comment: The RTC module includes a memory module which is also addressable via I2C hence the 2 addresses. Have you tried sample code like here: https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tiny_RTC

Comment: Looks like the RTC is running correctly but has not been initiated with the current time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by deleting the library downloaded using arduino library manager and replacing it with the library from github.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the example code from the MD_DS1307 library to find the settings on your RTC, when I first wired mine up the clock was not running and I couldn't set the time on it. After I enabled it, it worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you for help. I fixed the issue. It was caused by the library which I got from arduino library manager. I deleted it and downloaded the library from github. Now it works great.